# how to make ld treat Multiply defined structs/classes as an error?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, multiple-definition-error

EDIT-- clarifying the goal of my question:
I lose a lot of time diagnosing problems that I expect the linker to report, caused by an admittedly bad programming style, which pops up when e.g. copy-pasting a block of code from one compilation unit to another, and altering it.

I'm looking for a way to detect this problem at compile/link time.

In this setup:

**A.h**

```
void foo();
```

**A.cpp**

```
struct A { 
  int values[100];
  A(){ 
    std::cout << __FILE__ << ": A::A()\n";
}};
void foo(){ 
   A a;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
struct A { 
  double values[100];
  A(){ 
  std::cout << __FILE__ << ": A::A()\n";
}};
int main(){ foo(); }
// void foo(){} ===> this would cause a linker error
```

I would love the linker to report that the structure `A`, or at least the constructor `A::A()`, is defined twice.

However, g++ 4.4 links just fine.  Running the code shows that in this case, the linker chose to use the `A` from A.cpp.

```
$ g++ -Wall A.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
A.cpp:3
A.cpp:7
A.cpp:3
```

When a *function* `foo()` is present in two object files, the linker reports a multiple definition allright, but for the structures, it doesn't.

EDIT: just found by using `nm -C *.o` that both A.o and main.o have `A::A()` defined as a *weak symbol*.  This causes it to be 'selectable' from a pool of symbols with the same name.  Maybe the question can be rephrased to "how can I cause the compiler to generate *strong* symbols?"...

```
00000000 W A::A()
```

How can I detect this problem?

Comment: Defining a member inside a class like you just did implicitly declares that member as `inline`, such that the implementation will let you provide more than one definition of that member in the whole program. It's still required that all those definitions are sufficiently similar with each other (which I think isn't the case here due to the use of `__FILE__`), but that's harder to diagnose (and is not required).

Comment: @LucDanton: where *sufficiently similar* is *exactly the same*, otherwise you are violating the ODR.

Comment: @LucDanton: I see what you mean, but in this case, the `nm` output clearly shows that said function has not been inlined, doesn't it?

Comment: @xtofl Don't make the mistake of thinking that the `inline` heyword has anything to do with inlining (not that anyone should be blamed for that). It has to do with the ODR -- and here by using `inline` (although implicitly) you're asking for a special version of the ODR that makes diagnostics harder. Since you want *more* diagnostics, drop the `inline` -- plus separating definition from declaration is usually better style, too.

Comment: @LucDanton: Don't let the standardese confuse you, there is no stricter definition of *exactly the same* than the one the standard provides: *the code must be the same, the objects referred by the code must be the exactly the same object, except where that is impossible, in which case the object's identity cannot be used, only the value, and the value must be exactly the same*. Without that exception, this would be in violation of the ODR: `const int k = 10; inline int f() { return k; }`, as constants have *internal linkage* and thus there is a different `k` for each TU that include it.

Comment: ... also note that surprisingly, including this (as a header) from different TU and using `g` is undefined behavior: `const int k = 10; void f( const int & ); inline void g() { f(k); }` and the reason is that the address of `k` could be part of the side effects of `f`, and then the program would depend on which version the linker picked up, as `&k` has different values in different TUs.

Comment: @LucDanton: There is no contradiction there: *exactly the same* means not just C++ code, but that the generated binary will be *exactly the same*. The requirement is that it must be *exactly the same object* whenever possible, or else *exactly the same value and only use the value*. Granted a deterministic compiler/optimizer, the standard requires the the generated code will be *exactly the same*. Note that the exception is: *when it is impossible to require exact same object, only the value which **must be the same** can be used*. That guarantees that the compiler will generate the same code.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe the question can be rephrased to "how can I cause the compiler to generate strong symbols?"...

Try to restrict the use of `inline` functions:

```
struct A {
    A();
};

// Inside A.cpp
A::A() { 
    std::cout << __FILE__ << ": A::A()\n";
}
```

An implementation is much more likely to report an ODR violation for a function that is not declared `inline` (including those that are *implicitly* declared `inline`, like members defined inside a class definition), although strictly speaking such a diagnostic is never required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, and it's not a redefinition. It's how C++ works. Think about it — you put class *definitions* in headers (exposing just declaration is far less common). Headers are pretty much copy-pasted into every translation unit that uses them. It *cannot* be an error to have multiple definitions of the same class in multiple TUs. So, it's not something to solve.

Compiler/linker should complain if there are different classes defined under the same name, though.

Comment: ... and of course, the latter is when the problem _really_ hurts.  I have spent several hours, spread over the last decade, bumping into segmentation faults (best case) and corrupted memory caused by that problem.  Hence this question.